Azure Login in seperate jobs within the same workflow use different Subject Identifier
So I'm trying to set up a GitHub Actions workflow which deploys an ARM template and then deploys multiple apps to azure resources. Since I'm deploying multiple apps, I am trying to deploy the apps in a seperate jobs from the arm deployment so I can use the matrix strategy but for some reason the azure/login action uses a different (and therefor wrong) subject identifier which results in the deployment of the apps failing.
This is (a part of) the workflow:
name: push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop 
      - release/*
      - main
      - hotfix/*

permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: write

jobs:
  * other jobs *

  publish:
    needs: determine
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - projectName: 'ApiProj'
            publishPath: 'api'
          - projectName: 'FunctionsProj'
            publishPath: 'func'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Restore
        run: dotnet restore ./server
        env:
          NuGetPackageSourceCredentials: Username=DUMMY_USER;Password=${{ secrets.PAT_PACKAGES }}
      - name: Publish
        run: |
          dotnet publish ./server/src/${{ matrix.projectName }}/${{ matrix.projectName }}.csproj -c Release -o ./publish/${{ matrix.publishPath }}
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job (API)
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: ${{ matrix.publishPath }}
          path: ./publish/${{ matrix.publishPath }}

  deploy-arm:
  # Deploy the app (if approved when needed by environment)
    needs: determine
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ needs.determine.outputs.Environment }}
    steps:
      - name: Azure Login
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Run ARM deploy
        uses: azure/arm-deploy@v2
        with:
          subscriptionId: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION }}
          resourceGroupName: ${{ vars.AZURE_RG }}
          template: ./infra/deployments/main.json
          parameters: ./infra/deployments/main.parameters.${{needs.determine.outputs.Environment}}.json

  deploy-apps:  
    needs: [ deploy-arm, publish ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ needs.determine.outputs.Environment }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - artifact: 'api'
            publishProfile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_API_PUBLISH_PROFILE  }}
          - artifact: 'func'
            publishProfile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNC_PUBLISH_PROFILE  }}     
    steps:
      - name: Azure Login
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      - name: Download artifact from publish job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: ${{ matrix.artifact }}
          path: app
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: resource-${{ matrix.artifact }}-app
          publish-profile: ${{ matrix.publishProfile  }}
          package: ./app

Now, when the "deploy-arm" job does the azure login step, it uses the correct Subject Identifier:

subject claim -
repo:OrganisationName/RepositoryName:environment:dev

and the template is deployed successfully (verified this in Azure, all resources have been created)
In the next job "deploy-apps", the azure login step uses a different one:

subject claim -
'repo:OrganisationName/RepositoryName:ref:refs/heads/develop'

Can anyone explain to me why the subject identifier suddenly changes, and how I could resolve this?

The deploy-apps job depends on [ deploy-arm, publish ]. You set the environment to be needs.determine.outputs.Environment. I imagine the environment is not resolved here and the subject claim defaults to the branch you're deploying from.

Yes, thank you! Since the determine step isn't listed as dependency in the needs section, the environment wasn't resolved indeed.

good to hear it is working for you.

The deploy-apps job depends on [ deploy-arm, publish ]. You set the environment to be needs.determine.outputs.Environment.
I imagine the environment is not resolved here and the subject claim defaults to the branch you're deploying from. Adding determine in the list of dependency should solve your issue:
deploy-apps:
  needs: [ deploy-arm, publish,  determine]

